# JAVAFX: Popup dialog appearing on primary monitor when application is on extended monitor

Tags: popup, javafx-8, stage

JAVAFX: I have an application which generates a modal popup dialog which I have created on a stage and given my application's stage as the owner to the new popover stage . When I run the application and move it to my extended monitor, the popover still appears on my primary monitor.

here is the snippet of my code:

```
    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
    Scene currentScene=new Scene(borderPane,1015,175);

    Stage popoverStage= new Stage();
    popoverStage.initModality(modality);
    popoverStage.alwaysOnTopProperty();
    popoverStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    popoverStage.initOwner(control.getParent().getScene().getWindow());
    Bounds currentMouseLocation=control.localToScene(control.getBoundsInLocal());
    double popOverX=(currentMouseLocation.getMinX()+currentMouseLocation.getMaxX())/2;
    double popOverY=(currentMouseLocation.getMinY()+currentMouseLocation.getMaxY())/2;
    popoverStage.setX(popOverX);
    popoverStage.setY(popOverY);
    popoverStage.setScene(currentScene);
    popoverStage.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setX()` and `setY()` methods of `Stage` are expecting coordinates specified in the *screen* coordinate system. You are passing in coordinates from the current *scene* coordinate system.

Replace

```
Bounds currentMouseLocation=control.localToScene(control.getBoundsInLocal());
```

with

```
Bounds currentMouseLocation=control.localToScreen(control.getBoundsInLocal());
```